# Juniper VPN service not working - shows error 98

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I get this error when trying to connect to my uni's VPN using Juniper (It's not the only thing, but compared to someone who had it working this was the only difference).

```
IpcConn.error bind failed to port 4242. Error 98 (ncipc.cpp:85)
```

What can I do?

I should probably add that usually you can quit the connection by hitting `Ctrl+C` but that doesn't work either. It will get stuck, I'll force close the terminal, and entering `pidof ncsvc` (ncsvc being the app) will show as many processes as attempts I've made at connecting. Killing those and starting anew doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0):

Some other program is probably using port 424 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/madscientist/msjnc/issues/14)

`Crashplan` is one such program that uses that port.

To find out the program using port you can use,

```
sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 4242

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4242            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7490/java
```

7490 is the `Process ID` of the program and the program using it is `java`.
More information [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/) on how to find the program using a port.

Comment: Do you know if I can change the port that Juniper uses?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the port that Juniper uses.  What other program are you using that wants to use 4242?